# How do I make a slash command not usable in dms discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am making a discord bot and I want all the slash commands to not be usable in a users direct messages, it can only be used in the server the bot is in. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Command Specific:
[Discord.js Guide](https://discordjs.guide/slash-commands/permissions.html#dm-permission)

Global:
Add this to your `interaction-create` event before executing:

```
if (!interaction.guild) return await interaction.reply({ content: "Commands are only useable on Servers", ephemeral: true });
```

Comment: i figured out that using ```.setDMPermission('false')``` works out best